# JavaScript Objects passing arguments

Tags: javascript, object

I've been search for solution for this for quite a while now but ive not came across the yet.

This may seem like a simple question but i quite new to the objects in javascript.

My question is how do i get a get a object to pass a argument to a function.

there would be a function with an argument that console logs the argument.so

```
  function someFunction(arg){console.log(arg);}
```

and i wont to pass the augment like this :

```
var arg = "foo"
arg.someFunction
```

instead of :

```
someFunction(foo)
```

Comment: [Using a constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function) is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: You've removed your `foo` example. Notice, that strings have a host object ([`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)), and `'some_string'.length` reads just a `length` property of `String`. Like I've said in my answer, a getter is the closest to what you want to achieve. Please read the whole MDN article, it's very useful when learning basics of objects. Also using getters purely to call some functions is bad practice, it makes your code hard to understand. If you want to call a function, do it with a recognizable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for constructor function is what you need:

```
function TestObj (arg) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'getNLog', {
        get: function () {
            console.log(arg);
            return arg;
        }
    });
}

var foo = new TestObj('FOO');
// Usage
alert(foo.getNLog);
```

Notice, that you can't set value to `getNLog` after creating `foo`. The article linked above explains also, how to set a value to `getNLog`.

[A live demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gk9KL/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what you really want on this.

But this is not the way to go.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) you have an tutorial so you can have a better idea in how to use Objects in JScript, I am a bit rusty in JScripts so I read that tutorial last week, and it helped me a lot.

This code you posted is a bit difficult to understand the goal, if you could clear this, I can help you better.

Comment: i have edited my question i think its may make my goal a bit easyier to understand

Comment: yeah. It is better, I think the answer from Vishnu  it is the way to go for simple code, but the one from Teemu is a little more constructive and you should aim for a code with that quality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is what you're looking for :

```
var obj = function functionName(arg){
    console.log(arg)
};
var foo ="foo";
obj(foo); // will print out "foo" to the console
```

You could read more about [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and about [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) in JavaScript from the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide).

Comment: yeah i know about this and it how i usally do it just i would like to do it though a object like foo.length works

Comment: So you want `functionName` to be a member function of this Object `obj` so that you can call `obj.functionName(foo)`. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes that sort of but i dont wont have to have the (foo)